# How to write hex to file in python

Tags: python, hex

I really don't understand what is going on with Python.

If I use

```
f.write(data.encode("hex"))
```

Python converts my data into a hex string, so in the case of "hello"
I get the string 68656c6c6f.

However using

```
f = open('file.dat', 'wb')
f.write("hello".encode("hex"))
f.close()
```

Will just write the ascii of the hex.
The same is true of hexlify.
I need the hex in the \00 format, yet everything seems to want to give me hex strings in ascsii

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 3.x, we have a lib called **binascii** for Converting between binary and ASCII...

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'Hi')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> "\\"+"\\".join(["hello".encode("hex")[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len("hello".encode("hex")),2)])
'\\68\\65\\6c\\6c\\6f'
```

there now you have \ prepended to every 2 chars of hex